# Ligar 2 TextBox en C# WF (Usuario y Contraseña)

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un metodo para volver reactivos 2 TextBox, mi duda es... Porque al intentar **pasar** ese ¨Metodo¨, **a** una **biblioteca de clases** de WF no funciona. Si lo dejo en la clase de la Forma, si funciona de manera correcta.

```
    public static void Usuario_Contra(ref TextBox pUsuario) 
    {

        //Leave
        if (pUsuario.Text == "")
        {
            pUsuario.Text = "USUARIO";
            pUsuario.ForeColor = Color.DimGray;
        }
        //Enter
        if (pUsuario.Text == "USUARIO")
        {
            pUsuario.Text = "";
            pUsuario.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(82, 85, 100);
        }
    }

    public static void Contra_Usuario(ref TextBox Contraseña)
    {
        //Enter
        if (Contraseña.Text == "CONTRASEÑA")
        {
            Contraseña.Text = "";
            Contraseña.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(82, 85, 100);
            Contraseña.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
        }
        //Leave
        if (Contraseña.Text == "")
        {
            Contraseña.Text = "CONTRASEÑA";
            Contraseña.ForeColor = Color.DimGray;
            Contraseña.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: El error que tengo es que solo funciona parcialmente cuando lo implemento desde una clase. a difetencia de la manera **¨tradicional¨**

Comment: No agregues comentarios a tu pregunta. Editar la pregunta y coloca lo que necesites agregar.

Comment: Creo que tu codigo no funciona porque estas usando ref cuando sacas tus metodos de la clase parcial del form, quitales el ref y solo podrias pasar el string de tu TextBox. Si esa logica las vas a usar en otros lados tiene sentido quitarla y tener que navegar hacia ella para ver como funciona o hacer cambios, Sino me parece que esta bien que este en la clase parcial del Form.

Comment: Por otro lado, si queres mantenerla y usar esa logica, deberias recibir el TextBox y devolver un TextBox como retorno para asignarlo a tu TextoBox en el Form.

Answer (score 0):

¿Cómo estás llamando las funciones desde el formulario? Las funciones son estáticas, la forma de llamar una función estática es haciendo referencia a la clase sin instanciar un objeto, declara la clase también como estática, o quítales el tipo estático e instancia los objetos para poder acceder a sus funciones.

Para este caso metiendo en una clase estática "Utilidades", si estás intentando llamarla de la siguiente forma no funcionará:

```
Utilidades misUtilidades = new Utilidades();
misUtilidades.Contra_Usuario(TextBox);
```

Para usarla simplemente necesitas hacerlo sin declarar el objeto, de la siguiente forma:

```
Utilidades.Contra_Usuario(TextBox);
```

Comment: Porque no tengo que declarar el objeto para usarlo? En tu logica deberia hacer todos los objetos static de mi programa de esa forma que haga llamadas fuera de mi clase para poder usarlos, Puedo instanciar una clase y llamarla sin ningun problema.

Comment: Tanto la clase como el metodo son estaticos, uso de referencia un textbox y funciona solo la parte del usuario, pero no la parte de contraseña.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema realmente es otro. Cuando entras al método Usuario_Contra, en el primer if cambias el textbox de "" a "USUARIO", pero en el segundo if lo regresas a su estado inicial. Por lo que en lugar de usar un if necesitas un else if:

```
public static void Usuario_Contra(ref TextBox pUsuario) 
{

    //Leave
    if (pUsuario.Text == "")
    {
        pUsuario.Text = "USUARIO";
        pUsuario.ForeColor = Color.DimGray;
    }
    //Enter
    else if (pUsuario.Text == "USUARIO")
    {
        pUsuario.Text = "";
        pUsuario.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(82, 85, 100);
    }
}
```

Lo mismo pasa con el segundo método.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hice fue que mejor cambie la clase estatica, para poder tener un constructor que me guardara el texto del TextBox y depues ya con el metodo realizara lo que necesitaba.

```
namespace Funcionalidad_Formularios
```

{
    public class LigarTextBox
    {
        private string texto;

```
    public LigarTextBox(TextBox referencia) 
    {
        this.texto = referencia.Text;
    }

    ~LigarTextBox( ){ }

    public void Usuario_Contra(ref TextBox Usuario) 
    {
        switch (texto)
        {
            case "":
                Usuario.Text = "USUARIO";
                Usuario.ForeColor = Color.DimGray;
                break;

            case "USUARIO":
                Usuario.Text = "";
                Usuario.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(82, 85, 100);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void Contra_Usuario(ref TextBox rContraseña)
    {
        switch (texto)
        {
            case "":
                rContraseña.Text = "CONTRASEÑA";
                rContraseña.ForeColor = Color.DimGray;
                rContraseña.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
                break;

            case "CONTRASEÑA":
                rContraseña.Text = "";
                rContraseña.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(82, 85, 100);
                rContraseña.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}
`